# Laravel Vite build for production (Inertia) - unknown dynamic import

Tags: laravel, production, vite, inertiajs

I am currently trying to create a production build of Laravel / Vite /Inertia, when completing the build (npm run build) I have tried using the bundle but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown variable dynamic import: ./Pages/Auth/Login.vue
```

My vite.config.js file has the following:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
            
        }),

        vue(),
    ],
    css: {
        postCss: {
            plugins: {
                tailwindcss: {},
                autoprefixer: {},
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@images': path.resolve('./resources/images'),
        },
    },
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 200,
        rollupOptions: {
            output:{
                manualChunks(id) {
                  if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                      return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
                  }
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My App.js has the following:

```
import AdminLayout from '@/Layouts/Admin.vue'
import Auth from '@/Layouts/Auth.vue'
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: async (name) => {
    const page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`)).default
    if (page.layout === undefined) {
            page.layout = AdminLayout
        }
        else if (page.layout == 'auth') {
            page.layout = Auth
        }
        return page
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(createPinia())
            .component("Link", Link)
      .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el)
  },
})
```

The vue files sit under:

```
/resources/js/
```

and the files that I have are:

[image: file structure]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your Login.vue code as well ?

Comment: In react app, I was facing the similar issue with the same kind of directory structure. I changed the resolve method from the one which is given in the official docs and my error was resolved. This is just for idea if you can find some solution regarding this. I will share the solution in below comment.

Comment: `import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";

createInertiaApp({ ... , resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(
\`./Pages/${name}.jsx\`, import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.jsx")), ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Jaydeep gave the correct answer above for React and @[dlebedef](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/vite-inertiajs-persistent-layouts) on Laracasts gave it for Vue. In short, replacing the `resolve` property and value in `resources/js/app.js` with the following snippet fixed it for me. Formatting will vary depending on how your `app.js` is setup.

```js
resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")),
```